# how auto-generated constraint name was created in spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I'm curious to know how auto-generated constraint names are created in spring? As we know, it's identical in various environment after deployment phase. Is it a hashed string?

Comment: You could look into the Spring source code. *Use the source, Luke.*

Comment: That has nothing to do with Spring, it is your JPA implementation (probably Hibernate) that is generating those names, not Spring. So trying to find that code inside Spring is not going to work.

Comment: That's true @M.Deinum. I found a code snippet in hibernate repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [David Codrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636009/david-conrad) suggested, I dug further into the code and came across [this code snippet](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/98f52855c1cb67536ede28702d5f9e62409c6871/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/mapping/Constraint.java#L55). It seems that before hashing process (by [MD5](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/98f52855c1cb67536ede28702d5f9e62409c6871/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/mapping/Constraint.java#L105)), the name of the table with the names of the columns are attached to each other.